# Replacing part of a data frame with another data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

Let I have the below data frames (df1 and df2):

```
df1<-c(1,32,34,5,3,2,1,7,6,4,2,1)
df2<-c(100,100,100)
```

I want to create a new data frame(df3) as below:

```
> df3
 [1]   1  32  34 100 100 100   1   7   6   4   2   1
```

where from 4th elemnt to 6th elements are from df2. And all others are from df1.

How can I create such a data frame? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are not dataframes but vectors. You can replace them using `[]`

```
df1<-c(1,32,34,5,3,2,1,7,6,4,2,1)
df2<-c(100,100,100)

replace_vec <- 4:6
df1[replace_vec] <- df2
df1
#[1]   1  32  34 100 100 100   1   7   6   4   2   1
```

Similarly you can also use `replace` -

```
df1 <- replace(df1, replace_vec, df2)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
ifelse(seq_along(df1) %in% 4:6, df2, df1)
[1]   1  32  34 100 100 100   1   7   6   4   2   1
```